# What do we really inherit, when we implement a number of interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

It is said that Java  has an alternative to achieve multiple inheritance by implementing number of interfaces. According to the Java documentation about inheritance found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> A subclass inherits all the members (fields, methods, and nested classes) from its superclass . The idea of inheritance is simple but powerful: When you want to create a new class and there is already a class that includes some of the code that you want, you can derive your new class from the existing class. In doing this, you can reuse the fields and methods of the existing class without having to write (and debug!) them yourself.

and about interfaces [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html), it says that interfaces don't have methods implemented. They just contain method declarations. Also,  as far as I know, interfaces don't contain nested classes either. One more point, not all the interfaces have constant fields, many a time the interfaces (which I use for my work) contain just method declarations.

In that case, what do we really inherit from them, if we have to define all the methods ourselves? I know the other uses of interfaces very well. But I am not getting what it has to do with inheritance.

Comment: Interfaces *can* contain nested classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In that case, what do we really inherit from them, if we have to define all the methods ourselves?

In classic Java (7 and earlier), implementing an interface gives you:

- an "is-a" relationship with an abstraction,
- a set of method signatures that have to be implemented (to satisfy the "is-a" relationship), and
- an implied "contract" that says what the methods are supposed to do.

In Java 8, you also inherit `default` methods declared in the interface.

It is true that a class the `implements` an interface doesn't inherent any state declarations, or methods that can access the state declarations, as it would if it `extend` a class.  But the flip-side is that a class can `implement` multiple interfaces ... which you can't do with a `extend`.

In short, `implements` allows you to do things you can't do with `extends` and *vice versa*.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you Stephen C.

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces offer a contract, meaning that when a class implements an interface, then, by definition it provides a set of methods. How these are implemented is left to the class implementing the interface.

Consider:

```
public interface IPrint
{
     public void print(String str);
}

public interface IClean
{
    public void clean();
} 

public class CanonPrint implements IPrint, IClean   //Prints to a physical canon printer
{
    public void print(String str)
    {
         //Send data to canon printer
    }

    public void clean()  
    {
        //Clean printer buffer, etc
    } 
}

public class Console implements IPrint, IClean   //Prints to a console
{
    public void print(String str)
    {
         //Send data to console
    }

    public void clean()  
    {
        //Clean console buffer, etc
    } 
}
```

The above example, you know that the `CanonPrint` and `ConsolePrint` classes can print and clean after themselves, they have the logic to do it, the fact that they implement the `IPrint` and `IClean` interfaces guarantees it. Nothing is inherited, there is no functionality being extended, just a guaranteed a set of functions. The logic, etc, is delegated.

Comment: I would add that since Java8 it is possible to implement methods in interfaces.

Comment: Yes. I totally agree. But then, what do we inherit from them? Like we can directly call implemented public and protected methods of super class because of inheritance.

Comment: @NullPointer The inheritance tells what the class *is*. The interface tells what the class *cans*. For example, ArrayList *is* a sort of AbstractList but declares that it *cans* be Cloned and Serialized.

Comment: Ok. So it is just a set of common features which the two classes contain. This similarity is expressed as inheritance, isn't it?